# Jquery autocomplete is displaying in Rails app but I cannot interact with it

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I installed a custom jquery-ui install (1.10.2) with all features selected and the smoothness theme stylesheets.  I'm using Rails plugin rails3-jquery-autocomplete.  The form query I'm using is working and displaying the associated records as I type.  However if I mouse over the box or press the down key the popup disappears and nothing is placed in the box.

The following is displayed as console output when I type '00' in the box:

```
Started GET "/cabinets/autocomplete_cabinet_name?term=00" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-
04-03 11:24:06 -0400
Processing by CabinetsController#autocomplete_cabinet_name as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"00"}
   ←[1m←[35mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`i
 d` = 2 LIMIT 1
   ←[1m←[36mCabinet Load (9.8ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT cabinets.id, cabinets.name FROM
 `cabinets` WHERE (LOWER(cabinets.name) LIKE '00%') ORDER BY cabinets.name ASC LI
 MIT 10←[0m
 Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 10.7ms)
```

Does anybody have experience with this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the problematic code? Also an example exhibiting the problem on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) might be helpful.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748193/jquery-ui-autocomplete-menu-disappears-on-hover (I'm not complaining since your question's already answered and finished, I'm just putting this here for future readers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was loading jquery-ui twice.  Fixed.

Comment: This helps me a lot, I was trying to find out my problem about two hours, but can not before find this answer :)